# Node: Is it possible that http server on request return the content from a request module?

Tags: node.js, node-request

What I want to do is to make a request using the "request" module when server receives a request, and return the content of that "request" back to the client. Is it possible?

```
const http = require("http");
const request = require("request");
const URL = "???";

const server = http.createServer();
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  // called once for every HTTP request
  out_res = res;
  make_request((err, res, body) => {
    out_res.writeHead(200, {res});
    out_res.write(body);
    out_res.end();
  });
});

function make_request(callback) {
  request(URL, (err, res, body) => {
    callback(err, res, body);
  });
}

module.exports = () => {
  server.listen(8080);
  console.log('server start');
};
```

I got an error: `ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END`, I've been a long time without node.js, but my friend asked me about some code and I just rewrite as above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ofcourse you can do that

```
server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  request({uri: URL}).pipe(res);
});
```

Just `pipe` the response of API call to your router response object.

Here is how I would advise you to write your server code

```
var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    if(req.url === '/' || req.url === '/index'){
        request({uri: URL}).pipe(res);
     }
    .... //other conditions

});
server.listen(3000,'127.0.0.1')
```

Moreover, you can/should consider using [**`express`**](https://expressjs.com/), it's really cool and easy to use to define routes etc

Comment: why are you using `.on('request')` ? why don't you specify this functionality for some specific call ?

Comment: If you have time then could you please show me how to do it? Thank you so much...

Comment: It seems like the page keeping reloading issue is because the URL is an `.asp`. I change it to `google.com` and it worked. Anyway, I appreciate your time and kindness:).